# Notepad++ Wildcard

Tags: notepad++, regex

In Notepad++, how would I go about removing the content in brackets (brackets included).

```
4, Bone Powder,  (Ryu) 2000
7, Bone Powder,  (DC_Terminator) 5555
7, Bone Powder,  (The_Lion_Elder) 5000
5, Bone Powder,  (Franklin) 3500
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the following [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression):

```
\(.*\)
```

[image: regex 1]

---

**Note:** If you would like to include the space following the closing bracket, you can simply add a single space character to the end of expression.

[image: regex 2]

Comment: Good answer...but wouldn't the `.` you added at the end of the second regex pick up _any_ character after the closing bracket rather than just a single space?

Comment: @martineau Oops. Correct! You can simply use a single space character. I'll update my answer.